# List threads that match one of labels listed rather than match all labels listed

Tags: javascript, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am fetching threads from Gmail API and as `labelIds` field I provided array with labels. It will return only threads that match all of labels listed as quoted:

> Only return threads with labels that match all of the specified label IDs. (string)

However, I want to fetch all messages that match at least one of labels listed.

This is my function:

```
gmail.users.threads.list(
 {auth: authClient, userId: 'me', labelIds: ["DRAFT","INBOX"]}, 
 function(err, resp){
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(resp);
});
```

Is there a way to tell API that I want all threads that match at least one of given labelIds for a page with a single API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you found a proper solution please post answer, meantime:**

My guess is that it is not possible because that is not how Gmail inbox works. It is not possible to preview pages at once for multiple labels, unless you want all possible labels to be included.

**Workaround:**

```
var labels = ["INBOX","DRAFT"];

for( let label of labels ) {
  gmail.users.threads.list(
   {auth: authClient, userId: 'me', labelIds: label}, 
   function(err, resp){
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(resp);
  });//end(threads.list)
}//end(for-of)
```

Basically this calls `list` method for each label separately.